# Float Action Button não fica fixo no rodapé com Collapsing ActionBar/Toolbar

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, material-design, floatingactionbutton

tenho um fragment com coordinator layout, recyclerview e um Float Action Button, e na view que chama esse fragment tem um tablayout que esconde e aparece conforme sobe ou desce o recycler view, ja tentei de várias formas deixar o fab fixo no rodapé, mas de toda forma ele sempre sobe quando desliza o recycler view

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

segue abaixo o código do fragment:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/frmLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="br.com.julioantonini.meuchat.ContatosFragment">


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerContatos"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    app:elevation="1dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_action_add"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/recyclerContatos"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"/>
```

e abaixo o código da activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appbar"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />


    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        app:tabIndicatorColor="@color/colorTab"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>


<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/appbar"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
```

Comment: Qual é o xml da sua activity? Atualiza na pergunta...

Comment: Adicionei o código da acitivity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se não tiver problema em colocar seu `FAB` na `activity`, você pode fazer desta forma:

```
...
<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/appbar"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>
<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    app:elevation="1dp"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_action_add"
    app:layout_anchor="@id/viewPager"
    app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end"/>
```

O que muda aqui é que o `layout_anchor` do seu `FAB` deixa de ser o `RecyclerView` e passa a ser o `ViewPager`. Além de, claro, retirar o `FAB` do layout do seu `fragment` e passar para a `activity`.

Comment: Será que é a única forma ? Pq são 3 tabs e ela só aparece na primeira, e após adicionar um usuário é preciso dar um reflesh na recycler view, aí terei q usar um broadcast pra fazer o reflesh né

Comment: Acredito que se você for abrir uma activity a partir de outra e, dependendo do resultado que ela retornar, você for atualizar alguma coisa, o recomendado é utilizar `startActivityForResult()` ao invés do `BroadcastReceiver`

Comment: Na questão de aparecer o botão só na primeira tab, você pode colocar um listener no seu ViewPager (`setOnPageChangeListener()`). E quando seu FAB estiver na primeira posição, use o método `show()`, caso contrário, o método `hide()`.

Comment: Quando ao ocultar, foi o que eu imaginei mesmo! Já o fab ele chama apenas um diálogo para inserir um novo usuário e em seguida atualiza o adapter do recycler view, o fab estando na activity, qual seria a melhor forma de avisar o fragment para atualizar o adapter do recycler view

Comment: Nesse caso você pode armazenar a instância do seu fragment como membro da sua activity, abrir o dialog normalmente, ainda na activity colocar um listener no dialog (é nativo ou você criou um customizado?) na ação em que o usuário é adicionado, e quando seu listener for chamado você verifica se a instância do seu fragment não é nula e chama um método do seu fragment que possa atualizar o recyclerview.
Se você não tiver entendido dessa forma, posso atualizar a resposta, mas você vai precisar atualizar a pergunta com o código do seu dialog e da sua activity

Comment: Obrigado Danilo, eu consegui fazer utilizando o broadcast já que o app utiliza o broadcast que ouve o firebase  e faz outras coisas, porem, você poderia, me passar o exemplo do código de como eu chamaria uma função do fragment através da view dessa forma de instância. estou engatinhando ainda no Android e todo conhecimento é bem vindo!

Comment: Você quer dizer chamar uma função do fragment através da activity?

Comment: Sim, dessa forma não precisaria enviar o broadcast nessa activity